# How do I change the Swagger default URL and use a custom one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have an API that I created in .NetCore 3.1 and have enabled Swagger(OAS3) using Swashbuckle.  By default when my app starts if brings up the Swagger page using this URL:

```
http://{port}/swagger.index.html
```

I would like to customize the Swagger URL so that it includes the name of the application that is running.  The reason I am doing this is because I am using path-based routing with Nginx running in AWS Fargate.

I will have several API containers running in the Fargate task and Nginx will receive the REST requests coming from the Application Load Balancer and from the path (e.g. /api/app1), it will route the request to the correct container port for the target application.

So, for example, I have three apps: App1 on port 5000, App2 on Port 5001 and App3 on port 5003.

If the user makes a request to https://api/app1, Nginx will detect the path and forward the request to port 5000, which is App1's container port.

However, to make sure that the correct Swagger page comes up, I need to add "api/App1" to Swagger's URL so that Nginx will forward the request to the correct container.  In this case, it's App1.

In other words, I want my Swagger URL to look like this:

```
https://api/app1/swagger/index.html
```

**What I've tried**

In my Startup.cs file I have added the following:

```
// Define prefix for application
private readonly string baseApplicationRoute = "api/app1";

            // Enable OAS3 JSON middleware
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.RouteTemplate = baseApplicationRoute+"/{documentName}/swagger.json";
            });


            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                var endpoint = $"/{baseApplicationRoute}/{version.ToLower()}/swagger.json";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint(endpoint, $"APP1 API - {version}");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
```

This compiles and works, however it is still using the same Swagger URL of:

```
http://{port}swagger.index.html
```

I think all this is doing is changing the location of the swagger.json because on the Swagger UI that comes up it is showing:

```
/api/app1/v1/swagger.json
```

My launchSettings.json file is specifying the "launchUrl" as "swagger".

I think I'm close, but I am obviously missing something.  To recap I'm just trying to change:

The default Swagger URL

```
http://{port}swagger.index.html
```

To my custom one here:

```
http://{port}/api/app1/v1/swagger.index.html
```

That way Nginx can detect "/api/app1" and route to the correct container.

What am i missing?

Comment: Have you tried setting `c.RoutePrefix` to `baseApplicationRoute`?

Comment: I have not tried that. Is it just "c.RoutePrefix=baseApplicationRoute" ?

Comment: Yes, I would try something like that. Also possible you can have routing conflicts.

Comment: Thanks Guru, I'll give it a try. You wouldn't happen to have a link that explains this would you?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue:

In the **Configure** section of **Startup.cs** I did the following:

First I added the folowing variable:

```
private readonly string swaggerBasePath = "api/app";
```

Next I configured the path using **UseSwagger** and **UseSwaggerUI** to use the **swaggerBasePath** variable:

```
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.RouteTemplate = swaggerBasePath+"/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
            });

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{swaggerBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"APP API - {version}");
                c.RoutePrefix = $"{swaggerBasePath}/swagger";
            });
```

Finally, I modified **launchSettings.json** to point to the new base path:

```
    "launchUrl": "api/app/swagger",
```

Then is was able to hit the Swagger page using:

```
https://localhost/api/app/swagger/index.html
```

I testing this with Nginx and it was able to route to the correct container.

I can easily tweak the base path (for instance to add the API version number) by simply modifying the **swaggerBasePath** variable and tweaking the **launchSettings.json** file to match the value of the variable.

Hopefully, this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @KSS.
This works nicely for .net core 2.0 + Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v2.5.0 as well.

Answer (score 5):

(I am using .Net 6)

I needed this because I was facing issue in api gateway. So, What I did, I left my launch settings as it is.

**launchsettings**

```
"launchUrl": "studentservice/api/swagger",
```

**I made these two changes in my `Startup.cs` file.**

Note: Your launchsettings url and routeprefix url should match.

- In `ConfigureService Method`, I have added SwaggerDoc

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("student", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Student Service Api", Version = "1.0" });
}
```

- In `Configure Method`, I have added SwaggerDoc

```
                app.UseSwagger();

                // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.)
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/student/swagger.json", "Student Services Api");
                    c.RoutePrefix = "studentservice/api/swagger";
                });
}
```

[image: - List item]

Comment: `UseSwagger()` and `UseSwaggerUI()` is now deprecated. Instead `UseSwaggerUi3()` should be used but I don't get it how to set there the endpoint correctly. How can I achieve that?