# Change the default Swagger URL (Swashbuckle library) in ABP IO 4.4.4

Tags: swashbuckle, abp, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm working with ABP IO 4.4.4 and I want to change the default swagger URL by adding a prefix
Eg :
swagger/index.html  -> mynewsite/swagger/index.html

I tried the changes mentioned in the post
[How do I change the Swagger default URL and use a custom one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376063/how-do-i-change-the-swagger-default-url-and-use-a-custom-one)

But the swagger documentation and swagger-ui does not seem to load. When I use inspect element in the browser it shows that abp.js is not found (404) and the console log show the same. Any idea on what could be done to make this change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.UseSwagger(o => {
   options.RouteTemplate = "foobar/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});
app.UseAbpSwaggerUI(options => {
   options.RoutePrefix = "foobar";
   options.SwaggerEndpoint("/foobar/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Support APP API");
   options.InjectJavascript("/swagger/ui/abp.js");
   options.InjectJavascript("/swagger/ui/abp.swagger.js");
});
```

Whats done here is the the js file abp and abp.swagger.js are loaded again in a relative path. If you chack the Volo.Abp.Swashbuckle wrapper a similar configuration could be found.